# ReferenceError: websiteCheck is not defined discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I was basically coding a discord.js v12 bot and NodeJS keeps giving me this error even though websiteCheck is defined. If you can help thank you so much <3

```js
function websiteCheck() {
    // im not showing code because it will advertise a website.
};
  const scheduledCheck = schedule.scheduleJob('*/1 * * * *', function(){
    console.log('Checking Status of site');
    websiteCheck()
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically `function` wasnt being read somehow in the script, it started working with `const websiteCheck = async function(){`. Now its defined and everything is normal.

I don't know why `function` wasn't being read but oh well.